# How to setup  java libraries with javaloader in Coldfusion8?

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, bcrypt, javaloader

I'm trying to get javaLoader to run in a Coldfusion8 application and I need some help to get me across the finish line.

This is what I have so far:

Inside **application.cfc**:

```
...
THIS.mappings["/javaloader"] = GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath() ) & "tools/javaloader";
... 

<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false" hint="application initalizer">
    <cfscript>
    Application.str = structNew();
    Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey = "someUUID_javaloader";
    Application.str.jarPaths = arrayNew(1);
    </cfscript>
    <cfif ( NOT structKeyExists(server, Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey) )>
        <!--- add path to class files to jarPath Array --->
        <cfset Application.str.jarPaths[1] = expandPath("/classes/BCrypt.class")>
        <!--- this will map out to: ...htdocs/classes/BCrypt.class --->

        <cfif ( NOT structKeyExists(server, Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey) )>
            <cflock name="#Hash(Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey)#" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
                <cfset server[Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey] = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader")>
                <!--- tried .init(Application.str.jarPaths) here, but didn't do anything --->
            </cflock>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

This was done following instructions from [here](http://cfsearching.blogspot.co.at/2008/08/how-to-install-poi-on-coldfusion-8.html) and [here](http://www.compoundtheory.com/javaloader/docs/).

In my **handler.cfc**, I'm trying to access javaloader and the BCrypt class like so:

```
<cfsript>
    pass = "some_password";
    <!--- this is accessible --->
    cryptonite = server[Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey];
    <!--- now trying to call init() with respective path to create an instance --->
    <!--- BREAKS HERE --->
    bCrypt = cryptonite.init(Application.str.jarPaths[1]);

    hashed = bCrypt.hashpw(pass, bcrypt.gensalt());        
</cfscript>
```

I can dump the cryptonite variable allright, but when I try to create the instance of BCrypt, the script fails.

**Question**:
I'm happy I made it this far, but I've been sitting on this for a few hours now with no clue what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully someone with more insight can point me in a direction?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Glad you solved it. But for next time, "the script fails" is to ambiguous :) How does it fail: blank page, error, ...? Always include the full error message (and when using java objects, include the full `stack trace` as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. There were a couple of mistakes.

To setup Javaloader with Coldfusion8 and BCrypt or a Java Class of your choice, do the following:

1) Put whatever Java Classes (the .java file, not the .class file) in a folder in your webroot/htdocs(Apache). My path for BCrypt looks like this:

```
  htdocs/classes/jBCrypt/
```

2) Do the same for javaloader. My path looks like this:

```
  htdocs/tools/javaloader/
```

3) In **Application.cfc**:

```
<!--- create mapping to javaloder --->
<cfscript>        
    THIS.mappings["/javaloader"] = GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath() ) & "tools/javaloader";
</cfscript>

<!--- Application start --->
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false" hint="">
    <cfscript>       
        <!--- store a UUID and emptry path array in Application scope --->
        Application.str = structNew(); 
        Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey = "your_uuid_javaloader";
        Application.str.jarPaths = arrayNew(1);
    </cfscript>
     <!--- check if exists --->
    <cfif ( NOT structKeyExists(server, Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey) )>

         <!--- put all paths to your .java files here, this is for JBCrypt --->
         <cfset Application.str.jarPaths[1] = expandPath("/classes/jBCrypt-0.3")>
         <cfif ( NOT structKeyExists(server, Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey) )>

            <cflock name="#Hash(Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey)#" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
                <!--- create javaloader object and init with all submitted paths --->
                <cfset server[Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey] = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(sourceDirectories=Application.str.jarPaths )>
            </cflock>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

The setup should be in the application scope as per [here](http://cfsearching.blogspot.co.at/2008/08/how-to-install-poi-on-coldfusion-8.html). This should set up all .java classes which you can now reference from elsewhere like so:

```
<cfscript>
    var pass = "a_password";
    javaLoader = server[Application.str.myJavaLoaderKey];
    // create an instance of javaloader-BCrypt
    bcrypt = javaLoader.create("BCrypt").init();
    // now you can call methods from bcrypt like so:
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(pass, bcrypt.gensalt());
</cfscript>
```

Figured it out reading through [here](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayCategory&ID=22). Turns out you have to refer to the **.java** file and not the **.class** file, which I initally did.

The following links may also be helpful:
http://blog.mxunit.org/2011/02/hashing-passwords-with-bcrypt-in.html
http://www.compoundtheory.com/javaloader/docs/
http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/using-bcrypt-in-coldfusion-10-370

Comment: .. or you could just put the `*.class` files in a `*.jar` and load the jar as usual. Though the ability to compile `*.java` files on the fly is certainly a neat feature :)

Comment: i think i need more than a white belt in coldfusion todo that... I'll try the next time around